# How to transfer Form values from one asp.net page to other?

Tags: asp.net

I want to transfer one asp.net page form values to another page when i click to submit button. But you know, every asp.net page postbacks to itself. Do you know any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at: [Cross page posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the values from the request object or if required store the form values in session.

Comment: How can i use request object? Would you please write a little example that includes something like Request["txtName.Text"] ? Thanks...