# Passing Variables to a new page, when clicking submit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, submit

I have a page with 2 dropdrownlists & a submit button.  I would like to pass the values(variables) of the dropdownlists to another page when I click submit.

Any thoughts or suggestions as to accomplish this.  I have done something similar to this using asp:HyperLinkField, but I this does not work in my current scenario.

Comment: A search for [asp.net values another page](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+values+another+page) gives you plenty of info to choose from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transfer Form values from one asp.net page to other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911129/how-to-transfer-form-values-from-one-asp-net-page-to-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place a declaration on the second page where data come from.

So you have:

```
PostBackUrl="SecondPage.aspx"
```

On SecondPage.aspx you declare where you can get informations

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/FirstPage.aspx" %>
```

and you get them by...

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    if(Page.PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack == true)
    {
        GetTheClass = PreviousPage.CustomDataClass;
        // or you find your control, and get your data
    }
}
```

Some reference.
[Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

[ASP.NET how to access public properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036422/asp-net-how-to-access-public-properties/3036710#3036710)

[Cross-page postbacks and back again retaining data from source page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736445/cross-page-postbacks-and-back-again-retaining-data-from-source-page/3736506#3736506)

Comment: this is what I have for the submit event... what else do I need to pass these two variables?                           Protected Sub Submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
        PostBackUrl = "LiveEventCity.aspx?STATE={0}&amp;CITY={1}"
    End Sub

Comment: Good Idea :).. That's why I started my answer with "What about" as it was just another opinion that would work. Not sure what the asker is looking for anyway

Comment: @user630581 Yes of course you can pass it from url - this is not post (as you ask) however, is just a link, and you need ether to make it with javascript, ether to make it after the post.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting them in session and accessing them from session on another page?

Answer (score 0):

cant u use this:

```
PreviousPage.VAR1 = cboBox1.Text
PreviousPage.VAR2 = cboBox2.Text
```

with PreviousPage being the name of your other page??