# How to pass a class object from one page to another in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application in asp.net. I am using a class with property fields to store data. And I want access that property field in another asp page without using `Session`. Is there any way to pass the class object from one `aspx.cs` page to another (like query string). When I tried to pass it through query string and when I tried to access it one another page, I got the compile time error `'cannot convert type to 'class' type'`.

Comment: you should have your users data in `Session`, and you can dispose the session fields you don't want anywhere. `ViewState` is not a valid option for that kind of use.

Comment: Here is an answer using post data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804549/passing-variables-to-a-new-page-when-clicking-submit/5804721#5804721

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways:

1. Serialize the object to a string and pass it through the query string (POST body better though)
2. Serialize the object into a JSON and pass it through the POST body.

I recommend to use the second option. However, you should reconsider the question, might be, there is better approach to your **root** issue.